# Button not clickable even though the keyboard shortcuts are working

Tags: javascript, html, button

I want to keep track of certain timers. Upon clicking the button the clock ticks down to zero. However, after adding in a background frame and image my buttons have stopped working. I've implemented keyboard shortcuts that initiate the timer so my javascript functions are ok.

```
<body align="center">
<div id="header">
<h1>Welcome to LoL Buff Timers!</h1>
<h3>Like us on FB</h3>
</div>
```

This is where I insert the background "frame" which I declared in my CSS. The middle is a white image that goes over the background and the HTML button elements set to opacity. I declare this to have a `z-index` of `-1` in my CSS.

```
<div id="frame">
    <img id="middle" src="white.jpg">
     <table align="center">
        <th colspan="2">
             <div id = "CustomHeader">
             <img src = "shyvana.png">
             <h1>Salazar44</h1>
             <br>
             <h3>Jungle</h3>
             <h5>Shyvana</h5>
     </div>
        </th>
     <tr>
         <td>
            <div id="container">
             <div id = "buffs">
                 <label class="title">Blue Buff:</label>
                 <br>
                 <button class="buffbutton" type="button" id="yosb" onclick="startBlue();">Start Blue</button>
                 <label class="bluetime" id="mins">05:</label>
                 <label class="bluetime" id="sec">00</label>
                 </td>
                 <td>
                 <label class="title">Red Buff:</label>
                 <br>
                 <button class="buffbutton" type="button" id="yosr" onclick="startRed();">Start Red</button>
                 <label class="redtime" id="mins1">05:</label>
                 <label class="redtime" id="sec1">00</label>
             </div>
         </td>
     </tr>
         <tr>
         <td>
             <div id="globalobj">
                 <label class="title">Dragon:</label>
                 <br>
                 <button class="buffbutton" type="button" id="drag" onclick="startDrag();">Start Drag</button>
                 <label class="dragtime" id="mins2">06:</label>
                 <label class="dragtime" id="sec2">00</label>
             </td>
             <td>
                 <label class="title">Baron:</label>
                 <br>
                 <button class="buffbutton" type="button" id="worm" onclick="startWorm();">Start Baron</button>
                 <label class="wurmtime" id="mins3">07:</label>
                 <label class="wurmtime" id="sec3">00</label>
             </div>
         </div>
         </td>
     </tr>
     </table>
 </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: No way to know what's not working without the code-behind. Would you mind creating a quick jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes! Please give me a moment.

Comment: Post your CSS here please.

Comment: Here it is, you cant see the images or hear the sound but I hope this is alright http://jsfiddle.net/Cyf4Z/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
#frame{
    position: absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Cyf4Z/1/show/

Buttons are now clickable, but some error with the script/jsfiddle, try changing in your code.

Comment: Ok that works thanks for helping me! Do you have any idea why those CSS elements would cause the buttons to behave that way? Is it because of the image?

Comment: no, it's because of [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: Not enough rep or i'd give you some =/ almost there though! When I get it i'll come back!